# Bughouse chess tournament pairing software?

Tags: software, bughouse

Does anyone know of a (free) program which could be used to organize a bughouse chess tournament?

Where in each round the partner you have would change. (With the basic idea to put a good and 'less good' player in the same team.) The good player would be defined as the one with the most bughouse team wins.

Or how should I try to manage such a tournament? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is no pairing program which can do what you want. No program exists to change the partners every round according to the previous results. Pairing programs also try and avoid pairing players or teams which have played before.

Exactly how the partners would vary and how you would decide who had played whom is not clearly defined in your system. Your idea needs more work.

Comment: What kind of pairing (software) would you use for a bughouse chess tournament?

Comment: If the partners are fixed (the most sensible option) then any Swiss pairing program will do. The Vega program (http://www.vegachess.com/tl/index.php/Home_page_English.html) is excellent. It is free on Linux and free on Windows for up to 30 players.

Answer (score 1):

Bughouse is not the only partnered game where this would be a problem worth solving.

[Here](https://ohioeuchre.com/HosTourn_Progrssive-Euchre.php) is a description of what you want for Euchre tournaments; in this case they call it a "progressive" tournament format (not sure why). It still involves manually tracking results (no software) though. If you really must have software you might have to do some more googling.

Just remember that if it works for something like euchre, it will work for bughouse also.

Comment: Although it is possible to use it for bughouse, I can't say I like the method in the link. It bills itself as round-robin, but it's really not. People who keep winning (or losing) will never play others who keep winning (or losing). If you have 32 players, you could play 99 rounds and still have eight people with perfect scores and eight people with zeros. And the fact that you only move one table (at most) means that those who alternate wins and losses will play with the same people over and over.

Comment: Maybe so. The point is that it is easier to find suggestions for how to do this when Google searching if one is not committed to the solution being designed for bughouse games.